# Hlookup vba after filter

Tags: excel, vba, filter, excel-formula, lookup

Hi guys have a problem with hlookup in vba.
Please help me to fix it.
my code :

```
Sub week_req()
Dim x As String
x = Range("m23").Value
Set ws = Worksheets("sheet4")
Sheets("SHEET1").Range("B3").Value = WorksheetFunction.HLookup(Sheets("SHEET1").Range("J3").Value, ws.Range("$G$1:$J$4"), x, 0)
End Sub
```

So my idea is to searcch id by using hlookup but i need to search after filter. In Range("m23") i have formula count which is counting how many rows do i need to go down to see this value and macro is not working. Please help me.

Comment: `x` should be an integer or long, not a string.

Comment: not working always the same problem.

Comment: Visible rows in filtered list might not be numbered 1,2,3,4 etc. What is the formula in m23 ? For a single lookup it might be simpler to just use Range.Find().

Comment: Never midn i found solution